# Map partial string from dictionary in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I like to map partial strings from dictionary keys to a Series like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(5, 1)), columns=list('A'))
df.insert(0, 'n', ['abcde Germany fffe','aaaa Norway bbbb',
                   'tttt Sweden','Croatia dfdfdf','Italy sfsd'])

>>> df

    n                   A
0   abcde Germany fffe  2
1   aaaa Norway bbbb    1
2   tttt Sweden         4
3   Croatia dfdfdf      1
4   Italy sfsd          2

d = {'Germany':0.5, 'Croatia':1.5, 'Italy':1.5}
```

Now I like to map d's keys to the n column to match partial strings and set the multiple. I achieved this by an ugly loop:

```
df['multiple'] = 1
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    df['multiple'] = np.where(df['n'].str.contains(k), v, df['multiple'])

>>> df

    n                   A   multiple
0   abcde Germany fffe  2   0.5
1   aaaa Norway bbbb    1   1.0
2   tttt Sweden         4   1.0
3   Croatia dfdfdf      1   1.5
4   Italy sfsd          2   1.5
```

I there a better, more Pandasly way? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I came up with

#### Solution

```
pat = r'({})'.format('|'.join(d.keys()))
extracted = df.n.str.extract(pat, expand=False).dropna()

df['multiple'] = extracted.apply(lambda x: d[x]).reindex(df.index).fillna(1)
```

#### Demonstration

print df

```
                    n  A  multiple
0  abcde Germany fffe  5       0.5
1    aaaa Norway bbbb  3       1.0
2         tttt Sweden  7       1.0
3      Croatia dfdfdf  5       1.5
4          Italy sfsd  9       1.5
```

#### Explanation

`pat` looks like `r'(Croatia|Italy|Germany)'` which is a regular expression that matches on anything of the options separated by `'|'` within `()`.  When used in the `str.extract` method, it returns which country is matched.  Then run an `apply` to get the dictionary value.  Not all series values will be matched by a key in the dict so we must `dropna` then `fillna` later.

Answer (score 4):

```
df['multiple'] = df['n'].str.extract('('+'|'.join(list(d))+')').map(d).fillna(1)
print df

                    n  A  multiple
0  abcde Germany fffe  7       0.5
1    aaaa Norway bbbb  0       1.0
2         tttt Sweden  3       1.0
3      Croatia dfdfdf  8       1.5
4          Italy sfsd  4       1.5
```