# How to pad dataframe with empty values when add list to new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, nan

I'm trying to add a new column to an existing dataframe based on a list that is shorter than the already existing columns.

The values of the list are based on a dictionary, where a value is returned everytime it is matched with a key.

I'm using the following method to retrieve the values:

```
 attending_dict ={ 'Jack' :'Yes',
                   'John':'No',
                   'Paul':'Maybe'}        


List_Attended =[]
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    text = row['Invitations']
    make_list = text.split()

    for keys, values in attending_dict.items():
         if keys in make_list:
             List_Attended.append(values)

 List_Attended = [Yes,No,Maybe]
```

So far I have tried to use .loc in order to fill in missing values but it yields this error message:

```
new_attending = pd.Series(List_Attended)
df.loc['Attending'] = new_attending.values

raise ValueError("cannot set a row with "
ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns
```

This is what I would like to have in my dataframe:

```
 Invitations Attending
 Jack Muller Yes 
 John Doe    No 
 Ryan Paul   NaN
 Paul Doe    Maybe
```

It would be great if someone could explain how to resolve this issue.

Comment: where are you pulling the data from, please also post the source.(guess you have a dict here)Thanks

Comment: Try `pd.concat([df,new_attending], ignore_index=True, axis=1)` to add a new column with different no of rows.

Comment: @anky_91 this is just a practice for myself so the data are just the random names in the column marked 'Invitations', I have added the dictionary, it's just arbitrarily marks people as yes, no or maybe based on the first name.

Comment: @Sumanth thank you for offering the solution and it does work, however it fills the last few column with a NaN and I would like to fill NaN's in where they occur next to the name (so based on the index I guess)- sorry for not making this point clearer!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
attending_dict ={ 'Jack' :'Yes',
               'John':'No',
               'Paul':'Maybe'}
```

Using [`series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
df['Attending']=df.Invitations.str.split(" ").str[0].map(attending_dict)
print(df)

   Invitations Attending
0  Jack Muller       Yes
1     John Doe        No
2    Ryan Paul       NaN
3     Paul Doe     Maybe
```

Comment: thank you this is great and works well! Just wondering are there any other solutions to this or how would it work if there is a longer string in the first column? Sorry for the questions, I'm just wondering as I assume that str[0] only takes into account the first element of the list?

Comment: yes since you said you want a mapping with the first name hence i took the first name only, i think you can look ino this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372247/map-partial-string-from-dictionary-in-pandas/37372433#37372433

Comment: yes that's true, it's is just out of interest - do you have any pointers for me where I could check this out? this is great though, thanks again!

Comment: Sorry i forgot to ad dthe link, added now. :) you can use the string extract and map together for partial match and map