# Map partial string from dictionary in Pandas(again)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, mapping

This is a follow up to a previous post [Map partial string from dictionary in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372247/map-partial-string-from-dictionary-in-pandas)

I modified the mapping dictionary a bit

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(5, 1)), columns=list('A'))
df.insert(0, 'n', ['abcde Germany fffe','aaaa Norway bbbb',
                   'tttt Sweden','Croatia dfdfdf','Italy sfsd'])

d = {'Germany':0.5, 'Croatia':1.5, 'Italy':1.5, 'Ital':1, 'German':0.9}

df['multiple'] = 1
for k, v in d.items():
    df['multiple'] = np.where(df['n'].str.contains(k), v, df['multiple'])

print(df)
```

Obtained output:

```
                    n  A  multiple
0  abcde Germany fffe  3       0.9
1    aaaa Norway bbbb  7       1.0
2         tttt Sweden  5       1.0
3      Croatia dfdfdf  8       1.5
4          Italy sfsd  3       1.0
```

Expected:

```
                    n  A  multiple
0  abcde Germany fffe  3       0.5
1    aaaa Norway bbbb  7       1.0
2         tttt Sweden  5       1.0
3      Croatia dfdfdf  8       1.5
4          Italy sfsd  3       1.5
```

Suggestions on how to obtain the expected output will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach(similar to the linked post) which extracts the word in keys of dictionary and then maps the values using `series.map` then `fillna` with `1` where there is no match:

```
pat = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(d.keys()))
df['multiple'] = df['n'].str.extract('('+pat+')',expand=False).map(d).fillna(1)
```

---

```
print(df)
                    n  A  multiple
0  abcde Germany fffe  5       0.5
1    aaaa Norway bbbb  4       1.0
2         tttt Sweden  1       1.0
3      Croatia dfdfdf  8       1.5
4          Italy sfsd  0       1.5
```

Comment: Could you please explain how the `expand` works and how the regular expression works?

Comment: @Natasha `expand=False` returns a series instead of a dataframe when the pattern returns 1 group, we can then leverage `series.map` with the dictionary , `|.join(d.keys()` returns the keys in the dictionary joined by `|` which is is used to extract full matching words by word boundary: `r'\b'` , you can refer [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for mode details

Comment: The expected output of `pat` is `\b(?:Germany|Croatia|Italy|Ital|German)\b ?
`

Comment: @Natasha `''\\b(?:Germany|Croatia|Italy|Ital|German)\\b''`,  `r` is used for escaping the `\\`